# bxSlider current slide number display / total slides display

Tags: counter, slide, bxslider

I would like to build bxslider with pagination in the format of getCurrentSlide / getSlideCount. Something like [here](http://diary.chopard.com/precious-temptations-bejewelled-treats).

my html code:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
<div class="counter">1 / 10</div>
```

JS code:

```
jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pager: true,
  auto: false,
  controls: true
});
```

I assume, i need to use getCurrentSlide / getSlideCount, but i didn't find any examples.

Any help, would be appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

bxSlider has short pager ;)

`$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'short'
});`

Answer (score 4):

you can do it like this;

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({ 
    nextSelector: '.next-slide',
    nextText: '>',  
    prevSelector: '.prev-slide',
    prevText: '<',
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: false, 
    auto: true,
    autoControls: false,
    onSlideAfter: function(){    
        $('.slide-number').text((slider.getCurrentSlide()+1)+'/'+slider.getSlideCount());   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Append this code within your header

```
<script>
(function ($) {
     //bxslider
     function insertCount(slide_curr, slide_count) {
         $('#slide-counter').html('<strong>' + (slide_curr + 1) + '</strong>/' + slide_count);
     };

        var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            pager: false,
            captions:true,
            onSliderLoad: function () {
                var slide_count = slider.getSlideCount();
                var slide_curr = slider.getCurrentSlide();
                insertCount(slide_curr, slide_count);
            },
            onSlideNext: function () {
                var slide_count = slider.getSlideCount();
                var slide_curr = slider.getCurrentSlide();
                insertCount(slide_curr, slide_count);
            },
            onSlidePrev: function () {
                var slide_count = slider.getSlideCount();
                var slide_curr = slider.getCurrentSlide();
                insertCount(slide_curr, slide_count);
            }
        });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

add  just after the close ul().You are done and should display the total and current index hope this helps.

solution [Instruction and Demo can be found here](http://www.antimath.info/jquery/bxslider-slides-counter/)

Comment: U can move `var slide_count = slider.getSlideCount(); var slide_curr = slider.getCurrentSlide();` inside `insertCount` function